# To make multiple rotated copies of a 3D surface

Tags: visualization

Instead of a `Graphics` primitive I wish to plug in a surface generated by ParametricPlot3D and copy rotate to show several objects. How is it done?

```
CYL[u_, w_] = 
  ParametricPlot3D[ { Cos[u], Sin[u], w}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {w, 0, 1}]

 Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[CYL[u, w]], 
  Table[{RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, 1}], {Cos[a], Sin[a], a /3}}, {a, 0,
     4 Pi, .2}]], Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
surface = First@ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], w}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {w, 0, 1}];

Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[surface, 
  Table[{RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, 1}], {Cos[a], Sin[a], a/3}}, {a, 0, 4 Pi, .2}]],
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]